# How RENAME statement works actually?

Tags: mysql, sql

To rename any table in SQL we use following command:

```
RENAME OldTableName TO NewTableName
```

How does this work internally?

My assumption is it probably first creates a table with NewTableName using `AS SELECT`, then deletes the old table with `DROP`, just like we did when renaming files when handling files in C. Am I right, or does it work differently?

Comment: Why on hold?
Can anybody plz help me how to overcome from this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get some help from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html):-

> **The rename operation is done atomically**, which means that no other
> session can access any of the tables while the rename is running. For
> example, if you have an existing table old_table, you can create
> another table new_table that has the same structure but is empty, and
> then replace the existing table with the empty one as follows
> (assuming that backup_table does not already exist).
> ...............
>
> When you execute RENAME, you cannot have any locked tables or active
> transactions. You must also have the ALTER and DROP privileges on the
> original table, and the CREATE and INSERT privileges on the new table.
>
> If MySQL encounters any errors in a multiple-table rename, it does a
> reverse rename for all renamed tables to return everything to its
> original state.

Answer (score 5):

It works differently.  The data isn't copied.  The name of the table is simply updated in the metadata tables -- along with references to things like triggers, and so on.